# Convert Fire-Painting form Java to JavaScript with unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have following Java-Code, that painting a fire effect:

** Sample Call**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimplePaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimplePaint();
    }

    public SimplePaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class PaintPane extends JPanel {
        FirePainter f;
        PaintPane() {

            f = new FirePainter(200, 200, 100, 5);
        }

        int index = 0;
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            repaint();
            f.paint(g, 0, 0, 100);
            f.move();
        }

    }

}
```

**Class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FirePainter {
  private int width = -1;
  private int height = -1;
  private int width_new = -1;
  private int height_new = -1;
  private int line_height = -1;
  private Image image;
  private MemoryImageSource image_source;
  private long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
  
  private int fireIntensity;
  private long lastMoveTime = 0L;
  private int[] firePixels;
  private int shift = 0;
  private static final int[] i = { 4, 12, 20, 30 };
  private static final int[] colorsWarm;
  private static final int[] colorsCold;
  private int[] lightness;
  private int[] morphTargets;
  
  public static void fillWithColor(int[] pixels, int min, int max, int redStart, int redEnd, int greenStart, int greenEnd, int blueStart, int blueEnd, int alphaStart, int alphaEnd)
  {
    int segmentLength = max - min;
    for (int index = 0; index < segmentLength; index++) {
        pixels[(min + index)] = createColor(
              (redStart * (segmentLength - index) + blueStart * index) / segmentLength,
              (redEnd * (segmentLength - index) + blueEnd * index) / segmentLength,
              (greenStart * (segmentLength - index) + alphaStart * index) / segmentLength,
              (greenEnd * (segmentLength - index) + alphaEnd * index) / segmentLength
    );
    }
  }
  
  public static int createColor(int red, int green, int blue, int alpha)
  {
      red = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, red));
        green = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, green));
        blue = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, blue));
        return alpha << 24 | green << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
  }
  
  public FirePainter(int particles, boolean highQuality)
  {
    this.firePixels = new int[particles];
    this.fireIntensity = (highQuality ? 2 : 1);
  }
  
  public FirePainter(int width, int height, int scale, int line_height) {
    this.width          = width;
    this.height         = height;
    this.width_new      = ((width + line_height - 1) / line_height);
    this.height_new     = ((height + line_height - 1) * scale / line_height / 100);
    this.line_height    = line_height;
    this.morphTargets   = new int[height * width];
    this.lightness      = new int[this.height_new * this.width_new];
    this.image_source   = new MemoryImageSource(this.width_new, this.height_new, this.lightness, 0, this.width_new);
    this.image_source.setAnimated(true);
    this.image          = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(this.image_source);
  }
  
  public void move(int distance)
  {
    long timeCurrent = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (timeCurrent < this.lastMoveTime) {
      this.lastMoveTime = timeCurrent;
    }
    if (timeCurrent - this.lastMoveTime > 14L)
    {
      int elapsedMillis = (int)(timeCurrent * distance / 1000L - this.lastMoveTime * distance / 1000L);
      this.lastMoveTime = timeCurrent;
      if (elapsedMillis > 20) {}
      for (elapsedMillis = 20; elapsedMillis > 0; elapsedMillis--) {
        move();
      }
    }
  }
  
 public void move()
  {
    spreadBottom();
    addRandomSparks();
    coolFire();
  }
  
  private final void spreadBottom()
  {
    spreadToBottom(this.morphTargets, this.width * (this.height - 1), this.width * this.height, 280);
  }
  
  private final void spreadToBottom(int[] pixels, int start, int end, int value)
  {
      Arrays.fill(pixels, start, end, value);
  }
  
  private final void addRandomSparks()
  {
    this.shift += this.width;
    
    while (this.shift > 160)
    {
      this.shift -= 160;
      int x = (int)(Math.random() * this.width);
      int y = (int)(Math.random() * 24.0D);
      ignite(x - 7, this.height - 4 - y);
    }
  }
  
  private final void ignite(int x, int y)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        this.morphTargets[((y + j) * this.width + i + x)] = 1224;
      }
    }
  }
  
  private final void coolFire()
  {
      int endIndex = this.morphTargets.length - this.width - 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < endIndex; i++) {
          int newVal = (this.morphTargets[i] + this.morphTargets[i + this.width] + this.morphTargets[i + this.height - 1] + this.morphTargets[i + this.width + 1] + 2) >> 2;
          newVal -= 3;
          this.morphTargets[i] = Math.max(0, newVal);
      }
  }
  
  public void paint(Graphics graphics, int x, int y, int frames)
  {
    updateDisplayPixels();
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < frames)
    {
      graphics.drawImage(this.image, x + offset, y, null);
      offset += this.width_new;
    }
  }
  
  public int getScreenHeight()
  {
    return this.height_new;
  }
  
  public void updateDisplayPixels()
  {
      int index = 0;
      int canvasRowLength = this.width * this.line_height;

      for (int y = 0; y < this.height_new; y++) {
          int baseIndex = y * canvasRowLength;

          for (int x = 0; x < this.width_new; x++) {
              int pixelIndex = baseIndex + x * this.line_height;
              int intensity = this.morphTargets[pixelIndex];
              int color;

              if (intensity > 0) {
                  color = colorsWarm[intensity];
              } else {
                  int maxShift = 0;

                  for (int targetIndex = 1; targetIndex <= 5; targetIndex++) {
                      int shiftedIndex = pixelIndex + canvasRowLength * targetIndex;

                      if (shiftedIndex < this.morphTargets.length) {
                          int morphTarget = this.morphTargets[shiftedIndex];
                          int shiftAmount = 0;

                          for (int j = i.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                              if (morphTarget >= i[j]) {
                                  shiftAmount = j + 1;
                                  break;
                              }
                          }

                          int j = shiftAmount - targetIndex + 1;

                          if (j > maxShift) {
                              maxShift = j;
                          }
                      }
                  }

                  int targetIndex = index + maxShift + 1 >> 2;
                  index = maxShift;
                  color = colorsCold[targetIndex];
              }
              this.lightness[(y * this.width_new + x)] = color;
          }
      }

      this.image_source.newPixels(0, 0, this.width_new, this.height_new);
  
    
  }
  /*
  public void paintSnow(Graphics paramGraphics, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
    paramGraphics.setColor(Color.white);
    long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int i1 = (int)(milliseconds - this.milliseconds) * 20 / 1000;
    if (i1 > 20) {}
    for (i1 = 20; i1 > 0; i1--)
    {
      for (int i2 = 0; i2 < this.x.length; i2++)
      {
        int i3 = this.x[i2];
        if (i3 == 0)
        {
          if (Math.random() < 1.0F / this.x.length) {
            this.x[i2] = 1;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          i3 = this.x[i2] += 1 + (Math.random() > i2 / this.x.length ? 1 : 0);
          if (i3 > paramInt2) {
            i3 = this.x[i2] = 1;
          }
        }
      }
      this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
    }
    for (int i3 = 0; i3 < this.x.length; i3++)
    {
      int i4 = this.x[i3];
      if (i4 > 0)
      {
        int i5 = i3 * 3571;
        i5 += (int)(Math.sin(milliseconds / 700.0D + i3 * 49) * (i3 % 3 + 1) * 3.0D);
        i5 %= (paramInt1 + 37);
        int i6 = 1 + ((i3 ^ i4) >> 1 & 0x1);
        int i7 = 1 + ((i3 ^ i4) & 0x1);
        if (((i6 | i7) == 1) && (((i5 ^ i4) / 3 & 0x1) == 0)) {}
        paramGraphics.setColor(Color.white);
        if (this.v > 1)
        {
          i5 -= i6;
          i4 -= i7;
        }
        paramGraphics.fillRect(i5, i4, i6 * this.v, i7 * this.v);
      }
    }
  }
  */
  static
  {
    boolean alpha_available = true;
    
    try {
      new Color(0, 0, 0, 12);
    } catch (Error localError) {
        alpha_available = false;
    }

    colorsCold = new int[5];
    fillWithColor(colorsCold, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, alpha_available ? 0 : 255, 0, 0, 0, alpha_available ? 212 : 255);
    colorsWarm = new int[1225];
    fillWithColor(colorsWarm, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255);
    fillWithColor(colorsWarm, 32, 96, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    fillWithColor(colorsWarm, 96, 160, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255);
    fillWithColor(colorsWarm, 160, 256, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    fillWithColor(colorsWarm, 256, colorsWarm.length, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255);
  }
}
```

The result will be following:

[image: Output]

I have tried to convert it to Javascript with canvas drawing, here is an working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6k5q8jnv/

With following result:

[image]

Why is the result not the same like in Java?
How i can fix the sizes for that, because the result has not the expected size like the java sample?

Try to change the sizes between `width`/`height`  and `width_new`/`height_new`, `scale` and `line_height`